# How to set session for a specific user

Tags: php, session

i am trying to set session for specific user from my database (admin)
the idea is if the admin is logged in he will be redirect to admin page . and will have more privileges.

```
session_start();
require 'funcs.php';

$error = FALSE;

if (! empty($_POST)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
            `username` = '$username' AND
            `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1";





    $result = query($sql,TRUE);
    if(! empty($result)) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $result[0]['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $result[0]['username'];
        header("Location: index.php");
        die;
    } else {
        $error = TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: don't die... it's morbid and its not letting your session serialize itself :) ... return instead.

Comment: @Orangepill It is conventional and recommended to explicitly exit (same as `die()` ) after a `header()` redirect, to prevent any code following the `header()` from executing, which sometimes happens.

Comment: *exit* is also an alternative

Comment: Ok, but what about the issue i asked? how do i set session for specific user - in my case it's admin

Comment: @OfirKitlaro You need to be more specific. Do you need to determine if the logged in user _is an admin_? What is it you need assistance with? Note that although we can't see everything happening inside your `query()` function, it is very likely vulnerable to SQL injection, and possible for any user to log in as any other user including the admin!

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, i'm sorry for not being more specific, what i am trying to to is, file management system, you will have to login to upload your files, once you are logged in you can view your uploaded files, upload more files, or delete them(this is for regular users), i created admin user in my database and i want to set session for that specific user, so that admin will have different permissions

Comment: @Orangepill That isn't inside a function, return would just error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by adding a new column to my table i.e. `user_level`
this flag will help you determine which user is the admin and which user is not. Then you can simply assign that flag to another session value:

```
$_SESSION['userlevel'] = $result[0]['user_level'];
```

then you can do `if/else` checks to this value...

EDIT:
your table structure should be something like:

```
id, username, password, user_level = (normal|admin)
```

the `user_level` value should be either a normal user or an admin user, and by default when you set it. it should be a normal user unless if you want that user to be an admin then you set this column as "admin".

now going to your code:

```
session_start();
require 'funcs.php';

$error = FALSE;

if (! empty($_POST)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
            `username` = '$username' AND
            `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1";

    $result = query($sql,TRUE);
    if(! empty($result)) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $result[0]['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $result[0]['username'];
        $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $result[0]['user_level'];

        if( $_SESSION['userlevel'] === 'admin')
        {
           //go to admin page
           header("Location: admin.php");
        }
        else
        {
           header("Location: index.php");
        }
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = TRUE;
    }
```

now in your admin page you need to check if that user is actually an admin by doing this routine in all of your admin pages:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userlevel']) || $_SESSION['userlevel'] !== 'admin') //you can add more checks
{
   //redirect to login page
   header("Location: login.php");
}
```

something like that...

Comment: what do you mean by assign flag? im new in php please excuse me :/

Comment: can you describe to me what should i put in the user_level value in my database?

Comment: @OfirKitlaro - the user_level value should be either a normal user or an admin user, and by default when you set it. it should be a normal user "normal" unless if you want that user to be an admin then you set this column as "admin". so its either (normal or admin)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../database/connect.php'); // Database connect
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    if($username =="")
    {
        $erro_msg_au="<font color=red><b>"."Please Enter Username"."</b></font>";
    }
    elseif($password =="")
    {
        $erro_msg_ap="<font color=red><b>"."Please Enter Password"."</b></font>";
    }
    if($username !="" && $password !="")
    {
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where email_id='$username' AND password='$password' and usertype='admin'");   
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            if($row['email_id']!="")
            {
                $_SESSION['admin']=$row['email_id'];
                echo "<script language=javascript>window.location='dashboard.php'</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                $erro_msg="<font color=red><b>"."Invalid Login Information"."</b></font>";      
            }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML Script:**

```
<form id="login_form" name="login_form" method="post">
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']?>" />
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" />
<input name="btnlogin" type="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a **USERTYPE** ENUM field in your database ('USER','ADMIN') and have an hardcoded welcome page. As already told you have to escape username and password to avoid sql-injection (the example is for mysql)

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE
            `username` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND
            `password` = '". mysql_real_escape_string($password)."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = query($sql,TRUE);
    if(! empty($result)) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $result[0]['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = $result[0]['username'];
        $_SESSION['group'] = $result[0]['usertype'];
        header("Location: index_".$result[0]['usertype'].".php");
        die;
    } else {
        $error = TRUE;
    }
```

in the example the user will be redirected to *index_ADMIN.php* or *index_USER.php*. You could check $_SESSION['group'] to determine what actions are permitted or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written will roughly work for sending users who are in your user database and login successfully to the page index.php.  If the code you've written above actually is IN index.php, then you need code after your call to session_start() but before your SQL lookup to check if the user is already logged in.

If that user is "admin" then give the user the extra privileges you desire.  You will want to check the session variables in the same way on any page where you want to show the admin or logged-in users something different.  For example, your page might have a check something like this:

```
<?php 
// if session already started, this loads $_SESSION with existing values:
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) { 
    // Code for Logged members 
    if ($_SESSION['user'] === "admin") {
        // Code to show for admin user
    }
    else {
        // code to show logged-in non-admin users
    }
} 
else { 
    // Code to show not-logged in users
} 
?>
```